# Looking for help on showing result of cardinality and carestian product

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble putting everything together in this were I want to prove that ;

If$$ |A_{1}|=|A_{2}|$$ and $$|B_{1}|=|B_{2}|$$ then $$|A_{1} \times B_{1}|=|A_{2} \times B_{2}|$$

My thoughts:

Well I know that because that cardinalites of both the A and both B are equal, we know there exists a bijective functions $f: A_{1} \to A_{2}$ and $g: B_{1} \to B_{2}$

I also know the definition $A \times B=\{(a,b) : a \in A , b \in B \}$

I am thinking that the only way to do this is to prove that $$|A \times B|= |A| \times |B|$$

So I would have to construct a bijective function, but I do not know how I can do this. Is that the right way to do the question? Any help appreciated, thanks